# Adding a custom theme for design changes

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions, magento-2.1.7

I am completely new to Magento and am having some trouble moving around in the files. I installed the Magento 2.1.7 CE with sample data.

We had a company migrate all products and information from a Shopify store. Now I need to update the design. From what I gathered I need to create a new folder in the `app/design/frontend` files.

I am not able to create or upload anything. It says I do not have the correct permissions or there is an error. Everything in that folder is set to 777. What am I doing wrong.

I also have seen a lot about running CMD through ssh. I am not able to do any of that either. I get an error about not being able to open the input file. Please help or provide direction. I am using cuteftp for file uploads and the site is on a shared vps server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to unpack in that question, but I'll try to provide a few hints:

First off, to properly run a Magento 2 store, you will want to get `ssh` access to your server. It will not be possible to smoothly manage a store if you are still uploading files via FTP. Most hosts provide `ssh` access to the server. If they don't, you may need to find a new host for Magento. DigitalOcean has good tutorials about using `ssh`, [like this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu).

Second, if you are using FTP, I assume you are not using Git for version control? You should really use Git, if you aren't. And if you are, once you have `ssh` access, you can use Git to directly pull your Magento files on to the server. Much nicer. And use `composer` to [install Magento's dependencies](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install_composer.html) too if you can - it's nicer than installing the files from archives.

Third, Magento theme development is kind of involved, and you will hate life if you are trying to test things entirely on a remote web server (even with `ssh` and `git`). You should install Magento locally, either using WAMP/MAMP, the [Magento DevBox](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/docker/docker-over.html) docker container, or a Vagrant VM like [Magestead](https://www.magestead.com/). It will be much faster than uploading files to your server all the time.

Fourth, if the permissions are really `777` (which they should NOT be, for security) you should be able to do everything. The output of the `ls -lah` command in your Magento root folder will be helpful - but you'll need `ssh` access to run console commands like that.

Good luck! You'll really love not using FTP once you learn `ssh` and `git`!

Comment: I am very new to this. I am still comfortable with FTP so going that route for now. I dont have a ton to do and can just hopefully edit the LUMA theme to fit my needs. I have been trying to create a custom theme and use the luma theme as my parent. I have finally been able to add a new folder in the /app/design/frontend/company/vendor and created all the files necessary. However, when I go to content>configuration and pick the store view to add my theme. It is not showing... What am I doing wrong

Comment: I also am using putty to login into the server to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade. I read that a few places to fix my issue but I keep getting the error Could not open input file: bin/magento . If I try doing cd bin and doing php magento setup:upgrade I get Could not open input file: magento

Comment: You may need to set `bin/magento` to be executable, so it will run as a program. Check the permissions with the `ls -lah` command. You may need to run this command to make it executable, `chmod u+x bin/magento` as explained here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html